# copying strings from 2d array into 1d array

Tags: c, arrays

Im having some trouble dealing with pointers in C.

My code loads in a large string of characters from a text file

```
1378251369.691375   84:1b:5e:a8:bf:7f   68:94:23:4b:e8:35   100
1378251374.195670   00:8e:f2:c0:13:cc   00:11:d9:20:aa:4e   397
1378251374.205047   00:8e:f2:c0:13:cc   00:11:d9:20:aa:4e   397
1378251374.551604   00:8e:f2:c0:13:cc   00:11:d9:20:aa:4e   157
1378251375.551618   84:1b:5e:a8:bf:7c   cc:3a:61:df:4b:61   37
```

and then copies each line into an array (fullinfo[200][BUFSIZ]).

im then trying to asses the last two pieces of info and put them into there own array 
e.g.

```
 cut2line[0] = 68:94:23:4b:e8:35    100
 cut2line[1] = 00:11:d9:20:aa:4e    397
```

to do this I have tried strcpy and memcpy

```
     fullinfo[200][BUFSIZ];
     char cutline[BUFSIZ];
     char cut2line[BUFSIZ];

      while( fgets(line, sizeof line, pi) != NULL)  {

            strcpy(fullinfo[infoline], line);

             strcpy(cutline,fullinfo[infoline]);
             memcpy(cut2line,*cutline[25],100);
             printf("%s",cutline);      
             infoline ++;

    }
```

both of which give either

```
invalid type of argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
```

or something involving wrong pointer types.

any help is appreciated.

Edit to clarrify:  cutline contains the whole line fromthe input file which is correct, but when i try to copy the second part of the line into its own array i get the errors

Comment: You want to use the ampersand to make a pointer from an array element. Not star.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while( fgets(line, sizeof line, pi) != NULL)  {

        strcpy(fullinfo[infoline], line);

         strcpy(cutline,fullinfo[infoline]);
         //memcpy(cut2line,*cutline[25],100); This line is what's causing your issue I think.
         memcpy(cut2line,&cutline[25],100); //Use an & 
         printf("%s",cutline);      
         infoline ++;

}
```

Comment: It now compiles, but it doesnt copy like I expected it to, by using [25] wont it start copying from the 25th element?

Comment: If I recall correctly, by telling it [25] you are telling it you only want the 26th element, and not to *start* at the 26th element. If you want to copy *from* that element, you may have to use something other than memcpy, like strcpy()

Comment: Remember, [0] is the first element, so [25] is the 26th element.

Answer (score 0):

Several things here.

```
char cut2line[BUFSIZ];
```

This means declare and define an array of chars, i.e. an array of single characters.  I think you want an array of pointers to strings, i.e.

```
char *cut2line[200]; //not sure if the size is right here.
```

Next, since this is only an array of pointers, you will have to allocate what the pointers actually point to.  You could use malloc() or even strdup(), which does a malloc() under the covers.

(Or you could use a stack-allocated 2D char array, as you presumably know the length of the strings and the number of strings.)

The `*` operator dereferences what is at `cutline[25]`, so is expecting a pointer.  I'm pretty sure thats not what you want.  If you work with the above suggestions, `cutline[n]` will give you the pointer you need.

Having said all this, I think c is not the easiest language for quickly putting something together to juggle strings like this (and c is what I am paid to program in).  I would prefer a scripting language, perhaps python (or perl or tcl or ruby, whatever you are most comfortable with).  In fact a bash shell script would probably be better too.  With a scripting language, you simply don't need to worry about pointers and dereferences and allocs and the like.  The only reason to do this in c is performance, i.e. your input file(s) is enormous.